# Lock screen message from windows phone web view application?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

So i've created an application in visual studio for windows phone using a web view and I'm just wondering if its possible to send a message to the user that pops up as an alert when they are outside of the app? Every week I want the user to receive a notification from the application. After some searching around I wasn't able to find much information on this that is specific to web views so I'm not sure if this is possible using javascript?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create scheduled toast notification. You need to use [WinJS](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/winjs) or C# to do the job. You can call functions outside of the webview from javascript using [ScriptNotified event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)